# Две нитки и зажигалка

Tags: алгоритм

Есть две нитки и зажигалка. Нитки могут гореть неравномерно, они разной длины, но обе горят по 1 часу. Как с их помощью точно измерить отрезок времени в 45 минут?

Comment: @Типичный программист, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Типичный программист, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @zenith, ахаха, зачётно=)

Comment: @zenith, справа от Вашего комментария есть надпись:

"
Конкурс на лучший вопрос и ответ
"

Кликните, полюбопытствуйте.

Comment: Хм...тормазнул.

Comment: метки [загадка] [fun] видятся более верными.

Comment: загадка с брайнгэймс.ру.  
Простая. Главное включить фантазию.

Comment: И хоть бы вопрос передалали на тематику… Ну, там, есть два стула^W^W две тредобезопасных двусвязных очереди с числами, сумма значений в каждой из которых равна 60. Ну вы понели.

А разгадка одна.

Comment: никогда не любил такие задачи, потому что ничего общего с программированием они не имееют. если они предназначены развивать логику то внимание вопрос: если нитка горит не равномерно, то где гарантия того что та же нитка будет гореть одинаковое количество времени если ее поджечь с противоположных концов (напр. по очереди)? Если та же нитка с противоположных концов может гореть разное время, значит результат неточен. Если результат неточный результат приемлим то можно на глаз отмерить 3/4 длины нитки это и будет 45 минут. Для лучшей точности можно выбить среднее арифметические для 2х ниток.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что Старый вопрос с конкурса головоломок

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Поджигаем нитку 1 с двух концов, нитку 2 с одного конца. В момент, когда догорит нитка 1, поджигаем нитку 2 со второго конца. К моменту, когда догорит нитка 2, пройдет ровно 45 минут.

Answer (score 1):

Одну нитку сложим вдвое, а вторую вчетверо и свчжем их. Будет гореть ровно 45 минут.

Answer (score 1):

Берем нитку. Не поджигаем ёё. Берем часы. Засекаем 45 минут. Вот это и будет нужный отрезок времени.

Answer (score 1):

Одну нитку поджечь с обоих концов, а другую с одного конца, одновременно.
Когда вся нитка сгорит(с двух концов которая), останется вторая нитка, как правило она останется на 30минут, и после того как сгорит пожечь оставшееся кусок с двух сторон, и он будет равен 15 минутам. (Сперва 30 минут, потом еще 15 и того 45минут)

Answer (score 1):

Поджечь оба конца одной нитки и один конец другой одновременно. Когда догорит нитка, подожденная с двух концов - поджигаем оставшийся конец горящей нитки. Как только огонь угаснет, пройдет 45 минут

Comment: поразительно, а мы тут гадаем, как же это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Берем любую из ниток, сгибаем чтобы получилось 4 равных отрезка. Поджигаем. Когда 3 отрезка сгорят - прошло 45 минут.

Не заметил про неравномерное горение...

Comment: не катит: горение неравномерное. @dzhioev правильно ответил.

Answer (score 0):

1. Берем одну нитку.
2. Нарезаем её до бесконечно малых кусочков dx, считая что время их горения одинаково.
3. Замеряем время горения элементарного кусочка и получаем dt
4. Выкладываем необходимое кол-во кусочков dx друг за другом
5. Радуемся, что у нас есть матан и дополнительная нитка :) :D :D

Comment: если бы было чем замерить время горение одного кусочка, мы могли с лёгкостью замерить 45 минут

Comment: как узнать необходимое кол-во кусочков dx??
Сколько же нужно сложить бесконечно малых величин чтоб получить конечную!?
Притом, нельзя оперировать бесконечно малыми величинами в рамках физической модели, считая их физическими величинами.

Answer (score 0):

одновременно поджигаем первую нитку с обоих концов и вторую с одного. так как подожженная с одного конца нитка сгорит за час, то подожженная с двух концов - за 30 минут. когда догорает первая нитка, мы поджигаем вторую с другого конца. она догорает за 15 минут. 45 минут отмерены

Answer (score 0):

1 нитку складываем в четверо, а вторую пополам, поджигаем 1 из них с обоих концов, когда она догорит то же самое проделываем с другой...

Answer (score -1):

Сложить одну нитку 2 раза, а вторую поджечь и когда она догорит до размера первой, пройдет 45 минут.

Answer (score -1):

Сложить нитку сперва в 2 раза а потом еще в раза таким образом она поделится на 4 равные части. Далее берем за нитку в таком месте чтобы свисало 3/4 части нитки (мы ведь её поделили, помните?) и поджигаем собсно. так как вся нитка горит 60 мин то одна её часть будет гореть 15 а 3/4 этой нитки будет гореть 45 мин.

Answer (score -1):

Соединить первый конец нитки №1 с серединой нитки №2, а второй конец нитки №1 соединить с любым концом нитки №2. И поджечь середину нитки №2.

Answer (score -1):

Берем одну нитку и поджигаем ее, когда догорит берем вторую нитку и поджигаем ее, когда догорит.... а какой был вопрос?

Answer (score -1):

Только что задали такую задачу на собеседовании. Я предложил вот такой ответ, сказали что неправильно, но все-таки хотелось бы услышать мнение не только потенциального работодателя. К слову сказать, я задачу решил потом путем тривиальным, как здесь и предлагается.
Вот мой оригинальный ответ:
Поджигаем нитку 1 по середине (по большому счету это все равно что поджечь с разных концов т.к. сгорят эти 2 куска все равно через 30 минут, но для неверующих пусть по-старому, поджигаем с разных концов). Нитку 2 делим на 2 любые части и поджигаем с обоих концов эти 2 куска сразу после того как сгорела нитка 1. Эти 2 куска будут гореть (т.е. один из них сгорит быстрее, а второй будет догорать) - 15 минут, т.е. жжем их до полного испепеления.
30 + 15 = 45.
Жду комментариев.

Comment: если мы подожжем в середине, результат будет непредсказуем, увы. 
Как вы будете считать время? Если когда сгорит быстрый кусок, то получится меньше, если когда медленный - больше.  

Аналогично если вы разделите нитку на 2 части и одновременно их подожжете:
допустим, один кусок горит x, второй - y минут. x+y = 60
Если вы их сожжете с двух концов, но последовательно, получится (x+y)/2,
если одновременно - max(x/2,y/2);  

Ваш работодатель не шарит.

Comment: Да, сегодня с утра до меня дошло в чем я не прав, спасибо за комментарий это подтверждающий. Ну хорошо что я допер и решил её правильно со второй попытки.
А работодатель наоборот шарит, раз меня "осадил" с моей теорией...)

Comment: @ded: работодатель не шарит, олимпиадные задачи на собеседовании — глупость.

Answer (score -2):

А если сложить первую нитку один раз, а вторую два раза; если сложить один раз - это даст нам пол часа, а 2 раза - то даст 15 минут, сжечь первую, а затем сразу вторую.

Comment: нитки горят неравномерно