# Нитка и зажигалка. (Две нитки и зажигалка - 2).

Tags: алгоритм

А вот вам посложнее:
После неудачного эксперимента из [предыдущей задачи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/129352/%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) у нас осталась только одна нитка.
Горит она, по-прежнему, час. Надо отмерить 15 минут. :)

Призов не полагается. Тока палец вверх всем правильно ответившим, галочка первому, 20 баллов от меня лично, если будет представлено строгое доказательство.

**UPD**:Спасибо @Asen2 за комментарий.
Задача имеет решение, по крайней мере, на уровне алгоритма. На всякий случай, замечу, что неравномерность горения конечна. То есть мгновенно 99,9999% нитки сгореть не могут, оставив для оставшегося 0,0001% весь час.

**UPD**: скорость горения изменяется *достаточно* плавно.

**UPD**: решение уже опубликовано. Оно лучше, чем то, которое хотел предложить я. Поэтому Чуток баллов ушло и @nike. Жду строгого доказательства. (Я уже сделал, поэтому и наградил найка)

Comment: Поскольку нитка горит неравномерно по всей своей длине, то я думаю что можно доказать что задача неразрешима.

Comment: @knes, горит она тоже неравномерно ? Или сложенная в 4 раза и *слабо скрученная* обеспечит **синхронное** сгорание своих частей ?

Comment: @avp, да, тоже неравномерно. Хотя скорость горения всегда конечна и ненулевая.

Comment: @knes Я правильно понимаю, что неравномерность горения - это некоторая мгновенная величина? То есть может быть такое, что нитка горит быстро-медленно-быстро и это ничем не детерминировано (кроме факта, что вся нитка сгорает за час)?

Comment: @knes Если так, то увы не могу придумать решения =)

Comment: @knes Тогда определите, пожалуйста, понятие "достаточно плавно".

Comment: Настолько плавно, чтобы этим можно было воспользоваться:)

Comment: поделить попалам и поджечь обе с обоих концов? или операция деления нитки невозможна?

Comment: @Spectre, возможна. Если вы сможете найти середину, вы можете там поджечь, тогда нитка разделится на две. Проблема в том, что два получившихся куска не обязательно горят равное время. Внимательнее: скорость неравномерна.

Comment: Нужно отметить _ровно_ 15 минут, или с какой-либо доверительной вероятностью?

Comment: С какой-нибудь доверительной точностью. Скажем, 10 секунд всех устроит. Но чем точнее, тем лучше. В задачке с двумя нитками тоже не получится идеальная точность, строго говоря.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

поджигаем нитку в начале, в конце и примерно по центру. Ждем пока выгорит одна часть и поджигаем по центру нитку которая еще горит, и так до тех пор пока будет гореть нитка, главное чтоб нитка все время горела в 4 частях, после того как все части сгорят пройдет 15мин

Comment: Отлично. 10 баллов. Галку тоже ставлю. Ибо точность места поджога и правда не нужна. Спасибо @nike.

Comment: подожженную нитку не сложишь, чтобы найти середину)))

Comment: См ответ @nike, нам не надо искать середину.

Comment: я о том же...

Comment: @Spectre, отвечаю тут: в первом случае у вас два места горения сохраняются, пока не сгорит вся веревка. Поэтому время /2. В данном случае у вас 4 места горения переходят в 2, если одна из частей догорит. @nike и @nopster предложили как сохранить 4 точки горения до самого конца.

Comment: да, я даже [ответил](http://hashcode.ru/questions/129371/#answer-container-129444)

Answer (score 5):

Нужно поджечь нитку с обоих концов и в любом третьем месте. Как только одна из частей прогорит, поджигаем аналогично оставшуюся часть. И делаем так, пока вся нитка не сгорит. 15 мин

Comment: Возможно, вы правы. Сейчас проверю. Если да, то @nopster был первый. =)

Comment: Ага. Однозначно

Comment: @knes Вы программу составили?))

Comment: Нет. Чисто математически.

Answer (score 1):

Поджигаем нитку с двух концов, и с середины. Как вариант ее сложить пополам и поджечь получившуюся двойную нитку с двух концов. Как догорит - прошло 15 минут.

Comment: Проблема в том, что два получившихся куска не обязательно горят равное время. Внимательнее: скорость неравномерна.

Comment: это самый очевидный вариант, но ТСа он не устраивает

Comment: Возможно как догорит один из кусков, поджечь по середине оставшийся

Comment: Оп, теплее. Так, подожгли, дальше что?

Comment: Хотя сложенная пополам, и свернутая жгутом двойная нитка исключит разность скорости горения отдельных нитей...

Comment: Не исключит. Наоборот, она может добавить проблем: может начаться краевое горение, когда "быстрая" жила опалит с одного края "медленную". 
В общем случае, нитка будет гореть примерно со скоростью быстрой, так как быстрая подожжет \_во многих_ местах медленную.

Answer (score 1):

Делим нитку на много-много частей, эти части перемешиваем, делим на четыре одинаковых по количеству частей кучки, поджигаем каждую из них. когда догорят две части, ждём чуть-чуть (либо после догорания третьей части), — примерно 15 минут прошло. Хотя, в реальности это не сработает — верёвка, разделённая на много частей, сгорит быстрее обычной. Да и зажигалкой верёвку не разделить, а ножниц у нас нет.

Comment: Хорошая попытка. Но даже если бы были у вас ножницы: вдруг, разделив таким образом веревку, вы получите кучки с резко разным содержимым? Как вы узнаете, что "чуть-чуть", которые вы подождали достаточны? Можно ли как-то увеличить точность вашего решения?

Comment: Отличное решение! Немножко переформулирую(@knes ищи ошибки))):
Делим нитку на бесконечно много одинаковых частей, абсолютно случайно выбираем каждую четвертую часть(т.е. из четырех выбираем одну, а оставшиеся три не учитываем), складываем их в одну нитку и поджигаем. Т.к. частей бесконечно много и выбирали мы их абсолютно случайно, то эта нитка будет гореть РОВНО 15 минут.

Comment: >Т.к. частей бесконечно много и выбирали мы их абсолютно случайно

То распределение вероятностей времени горения будет иметь точнейший максимум в точке 15 минут. Однако, от значительнейших ошибок это вас не убережет. Существует ненулевая вероятность таким образом выбрать только медленные или только быстрые куски.

Comment: Решение выше абсолютно теоритическое и к практике отношения не имеет!

Comment: @knes Эта ненулевая вероятность имеет место быть, если кусков конечное количество, но их бесконечно много! А потому если она и ненулевая(как и будет на пркатике), то к нулю пренебрежительно близка.

Answer (score 1):

**Опревержение** популярного мнения **"Зажечь нитку с обоих концов и посередине"**

```
[|] ----------- |----------- [|] ----------- |----------- [|]
       5мин.        10мин           15мин        30мин
```

[|] - места поджёгов

через пять минут будем иметь:

```
[|] |----------- [|] ----------- |----------- [|]
       < 5 мин          10мин        25мин
```

ещё через пять(останется вторая половина нитки, хотя первая сгорит меньше чем за 5 минут, т.к. будет гореть с обоих концов):

```
[|] | [|] ----------- |----------- [|]
            5мин          20мин
```

ещё через 5, пройдёт 15 минут, но самый упругий кусок всё ещё будет гореть

```
[|] | [|] |----------- [|]
             < 15мин
```

Comment: Спасибо.=) Но по правилам, палец вверх поставить не могу. =(

Comment: Чего уж там, можно проще:
[|]2 минуты[|]58 минут[|]

Comment: это моя "работа над ошибками", т.к. я предположил неверное решение=)

Comment: Проще опровергнуть можно - взяли нитку равномерно толстую слева и равномерно тонкую справа: `==== ----`. Левая часть пусть сгорает за 45 минут, правая - за 15 минут. Зажгли посередине и с двух концов - левая часть сгорит за 45 / 2 минут, правая - за 15/2 минут.

Comment: Если бы скорость горения зависела от толщины, мы бы исхитрились измерить эту толщину. Но нить равномерная по толщине. Визуально предсказать скорость горения нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Зажечь нитку с обоих концов и посередине?

Comment: см ответ @temoffey и мой комментарий к нему.